# CSS - making div's background image look the same than the background image of HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page with a background image.

```
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url(bg_width900px_height675px.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This works fine when the background image is a beautiful landscape. The left side is darker and the right side a little bit lighter.

I also have a div which is wider than my screen. I would like to use the same background image than the HTML page is using. In fact, `background-attachment: fixed;` should be used and the background image should look 100% same than the background of my HTML page. In other words, the size has to be same.

Please note that I'm not looking for debugging help. I just do not know if my vision is possible to achieve and create.

**Update**

Thanks to blizzyb, it seems to me that this is possible. Here is my best code so far:

```html
<div style="width: 200%; background-image: inherit; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed;"></div>
```

Comment: it's not clear, please post the code

Comment: Could you create a StackSnippet or JSFiddle or CodePen that reproduces the problem so we have something to work with.

Comment: ' I also have a div which is wider than my screen ? ' - what are You creating ? :-)

Comment: It seems to me that I could not ask my question that well because I did it in English. I was not looking for debugging help. I just did not know if my vision was possible to achieve and create. Anyway, blizzyb already helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just add the `inherit` value on whatever property you need to be the same.

Comment: I used `background-image: inherit; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed;` with the div and it helped.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

you can define a class that you assign to the div tag.

```
.mydiv{
    background-image: url(bg_width900px_height675px.jpg);
}
```

if you have bootstrap you can also add the class .img-responsive which would avoid the image being distorted. Your div tag should look something like this

```
<div class="img-responsive mydiv">...</div>
```